# Does AMP have image width and height requirements for structured data values?

Tags: amp-html

The AMP validator is throwing an error for the publisher logo image width and height values and a warning for the image width value. What are the correct dimensions for these two image types? I can't find them in the docs.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are specific dimension requirements which you can find here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles#article_types

Your logo needs to be either exactly `60px` high or `600px` wide. And for the `ImageObject`, the `width` needs to be at least `696`.

Lovntola is not getting an error because his width and height are being read as strings.

Comment: Hi Andrew,  
how do you will set width and hight in AMP without META ?

Comment: Hi Lovntola, my team and I chose to use the JSON-LD markup approach but it seems like microdata is parsed differently, which is interesting. I would assume both will work fine but someone correct me if I am wrong. A sample JSON-LD Schema.org markup can be found here: [JSON-LD Example](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/metadata-examples/article-json-ld.amp.html) 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [description for AMP Logo](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles#amp-logo-guidelines).
i use without problems:

```
<span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <meta itemprop="url" content=".../logo.jpg">
    <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
    <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
</span>
```

and shows:
[image]